# How do I get `singleValueExtendedProperties` for MS Graph v1.0 delta queries?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to `$expand` on `singleValueExtendedProperties` for a delta query on my messages, but I'm getting an odd error.

**Delta query**

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/Inbox/messages/delta?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'String 0x007D')
```

**Response**

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InternalServerError",
        "message": "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: type",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "d7cf6c83-a062-4051-85b4-30a5aadf2e65",
            "date": "2017-10-06T10:05:10"
        }
    }
}
```

The [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/message_delta#odata-query-parameters) says this is supported. I've also verified (via the GraphAPI explorer) that:

1. the non-delta version of the query works *with* `singleValueExtendedProperties`
2. the delta version works *without* `singleValueExtendedProperties`

Is this a bug in the API or expected behavior? I know I can follow up with multiples `GETs` to pull the desired extended properties, but I'd rather avoid spawning several requests if I can get away with one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is limited support for the `$filter` query parameter on `messages/delta`. From the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/delta_query_messages):

> The only supported `$filter` expresssions are `$filter=receivedDateTime+ge+{value}` or `$filter=receivedDateTime+gt+{value}`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Marc! The `$filter` in my query is actually part of the `singleValueExtendedProperties`  expand param.

Does the restriction still apply? Is there any way to get extended properties for a Delta query?

Comment: I believe using `$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties` should work fine. It is the `singleValueExtendedProperties($filter)` that presents a problem.

Comment: You're right, using `$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties` doesn't error out. Unfortunately it also seems to be ignored - the [https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/singlevaluelegacyextendedproperty_get#get-a-resource-instance-using-expand] documentation indicates that the `$filter` *within* the `$expand` expression is necessary. e.g `$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq '{id_value}')`

Comment: I apologize, this was a mistake on my part. I somehow completely missed that I didn't get any `singleValueExtendedProperties` returned when I tried it. It looks like you're correct, you cannot return this from `/delta`. I recommend going the [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) and adding this as suggestion.

Comment: FYI the link to my suggestion, filed 10/6: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/31791508-allow-ms-graph-api-messages-delta-to-include-sing

Comment: 4 years later and it seems there is still no support for this...